# SELECT not initialising a value when null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
create table #Person (id int)
declare @ID int
SET @ID=9
SELECT @ID=ID FROM #Person WHERE ID=1
print @ID
```

I would expect nothing to be printed to the screen.  Why is 9 printed to the screen?

@ID was originally initialised with '9', but then it should of changed to nothing?

**Update**

I  have a .NET background.  Please see the code below:

```
Public Shared Sub Test()
        Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Connection").ConnectionString)
        Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim testInt As Integer = 9

        Using objCon
            objCon.Open()
            If objCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                objCmd.Connection = objCon
                objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Person where ID=1"
                testInt = CInt(objCmd.ExecuteScalar)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

testInt is initialised with 0 because nothing is returned by the command object (CInt(objCmd.ExecuteScalar)).  Why is TSQL not consistent with .NET?

I realise there is probably a straightforward reason for this.  However, I have never discovered this reason.

Comment: Because there is no match, so the assignment in the `SELECT` never gets run.

Comment: Because @ID is not set to anything because there are no results in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WHERE` filters out all rows, so the assignment in the `SELECT` never gets run.  Hence, `@ID` keeps its initial value.

This is easy enough to fix by defaulting the value to `NULL`.  However, if you want to ensure that the value gets set to `NULL` in the statement, then you need to return (at least) one row.  Aggregation makes that guarantee:

```
select @id = max(id)
from #Person
where id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the workaround. I have updated the question, which I hope helps answerers to understand  why I have asked such a  simple  question.  Could you take a look?

Comment: @w0051977 . . . A `select` statement is different from an assignment.  You can sort of think of a `select` as a loop . . . if no rows are selected, then there is no assignment.

Comment: OK thanks.  +1 for the comment.  It may be worth adding the comment to the answer in case anyone else is interested in this question in future.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this:

```
declare @ID int
SET @ID=9

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Person WHERE ID=1)
  SELECT @ID=ID FROM #Person WHERE ID=1
ELSE
  SET @ID = 0

print @ID
```

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the workaround. I have updated the question, which I hope helps answerers to understand  why I have asked such a  simple  question.  Could you take a look?